# getting two instances of JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I am a creating a certain project in java. 
I added a button to sign up the user on one jframe and on  button click first jframe dispose and second opens up where i have added a back button to go to first frame and login button. When login button is clicked a jdialog appears.
(I extends the jdialog class)
I have found out that if i click back button and then again click on sign up button, second jframe opens up which is normal but when i click login two instances of jdialog appears. 
Here is the code for first JFrame button

```
frontsignbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                new SignUpNew().buildDesign();
                frontframe.dispose();

            }
        });
```

And for second

```
login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new Login();    
            }

        });
```

And JDialog code

```
public class Login extends JDialog {
    private JLabel usernametext = new JLabel("User Name");
    private JLabel userpasswordtext = new JLabel("Password");
    private JLabel message = new JLabel();
    private JTextField userfield =  new JTextField();
    private JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
    private JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    {
        setTitle("Login");
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setLocation(400, 300);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        usernametext.setBounds(20, 20, 80, 10);
        userpasswordtext.setBounds(20, 80, 80, 10);
        userfield.setBounds(150, 20, 100, 20);
        password.setBounds(150, 80, 100, 20);
        submit.setBounds(75, 140, 100, 30);
        message.setBounds(140, 240, 230, 30);
        add(usernametext);
        add(userpasswordtext);
        add(userfield);
        add(password);
        add(submit);
        add(message);
    }
```

Any idea why this happens. I want to fix this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we also can reproduce your problem, and can debug a solution for you. Please don't post your entire project, but make a new small runnable class instead (or maximum 2 classes), that demonstrates your problem.